# How to notify the front end that it needs to refresh after setting a custom claim with Firebase cloud functions onCreate listener

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to initialize a user upon registration with a `isUSer` role using custom claims and the `onCreate` listener. I've got it to set the correct custom claim but the front end is aware of it only after a full page refresh.

I've been following this article, https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims?authuser=0#logic, to notify the front end that it needs to refresh the token in order to get the latest changes on the custom claims object, but to be honest I don't quite fully understand what's going on in the article.

Would someone be able to help me successfully do this with the firestore database ?

This is my current cloud function:

```
exports.initializeUserRole = functions.auth.user().onCreate(user => {
    return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, {
        isUser: true
    }).then(() => {
        return null;
    });
});
```

I've tried adapting the real-time database example provided in the article above to the firestore database but I've been unsuccessful.

```
exports.initializeUserRole = functions.auth.user().onCreate(user => {
    return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, {
        isUser: true
    }).then(() => {
        // get the user with the updated claims
        return admin.auth().getUser(user.uid);
    }).then(user => {
        user.metadata.set({
            refreshTime: new Date().getTime()
        });
        return null;
    })
});
```

I thought I could simply set `refreshTime` on the user metadata but there's no such property on the metadata object.

In the linked article, does the metadataRef example provided not actually live on the user object but instead somewhere else in the database ?

```
const metadataRef = admin.database().ref("metadata/" + user.uid);
```

If anyone could at least point me in the right direction on how to adapt the real-time database example in the article to work with the firestore database that would be of immense help.

If my description doesn't make sense or is missing vital information let me know and I'll amend it.

Thanks.

Comment: `metadata` is an actual custom field in the database, not a built-in property of the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example is using data stored in the Realtime Database at a path of the form `metadata/[userID]/refreshTime`.

To do the same thing in Firestore you will need to create a Collection named `metadata` and add a Document for each user. The Document ID will be the value of `user.uid`. Those documents will need a `timestamp` field named `refreshTime`.

After that, all you need to do is update that field on the corresponding Document after the custom claim has been set for the user. On the client side, you will subscribe to changes for the user's `metadata` Document and update in response to that.

Here is an example of how I did it in one of my projects. My equivalent of the *metadata* collection is named *userTokens*. I use a transaction to prevent partial database changes in the case that any of the steps fail.

**Note:** My function uses some modern JavaScript syntax that is being transpiled with Babel before uploading.

```
exports.initializeUserData = functions.auth.user().onCreate(async user => {
  await firestore.collection('userTokens').doc(user.uid).set({ accountStatus: 'pending' })

  const tokenRef = firestore.collection('userTokens').doc(user.uid)
  const userRef = firestore.collection('users').doc(user.uid)
  const permissionsRef = firestore.collection('userPermissions').doc(user.email)

  await firestore.runTransaction(async transaction => {
    const permissionsDoc = await transaction.get(permissionsRef)
    const permissions = permissionsDoc.data();
    const customClaims = {
      admin: permissions ? permissions.admin : false,
      hasAccess: permissions ? permissions.hasAccess : false,
    };

    transaction.set(userRef, { name: user.displayName, email: user.email, getEmails: customClaims.hasAccess })
    await admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, customClaims)
    transaction.update(tokenRef, { accountStatus: 'ready', refreshTime: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp() })
  });
})
```

Comment: Ah that makes a lot more sense. Thank you for the help and insight on your approach. Really interesting to see how you decide if a user should be an admin or not upon signing up.